# Montar um script de ALTER TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu tenho este select que me retorna o nome das tabelas que me interessam:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_AUD' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'REVTYPE' GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

A partir deste resultado eu gostaria de montar um script com muitos `ALTER TABLE <TABELA> ALTER COLUMN REV smallint;`.

Como posso fazer pra gerar este script ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode usar o `CONCAT`, gerando uma *query* para cada `table_name`:

```
SELECT
   CONCAT( 'ALTER TABLE ', table_name, ' ALTER COLUMN REV smallint;') AS linha
FROM
   information_schema.columns
WHERE
   table_name LIKE '%_AUD' AND column_name = 'REVTYPE'
GROUP BY 
   table_name
```

O `CONCAT` está disponível no 2012, em versões anteriores pode fazer algo concatenando assim:

```
SELECT
    ('ALTER TABLE ' + table_Name + ' ALTER COLUMN REV smallint;' )
```

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.